# Create os.DirEntry

Tags: python-3.x, scandir

Does anyone have a hack to create an `os.DirEntry` object other than listing the containing directory?

I want to use that for 2 purposes:

1. tests
2. API where container and contained are queried at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.5 os.DirEntry is not yet exposed.

Details: https://bugs.python.org/issue27038

Python 3.6 exposes `os.DirEntry` type, but it cannot be instantiated.

On Python 3.5 a type() on a DirEntry object returns posix.DirEntry

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `os.DirEntry` is a low-level class not intended to be instantiated. For tests and things, you can create a mock `PseudoDirEntry` class that mimics the things you want, for example (taken from [another answer I wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618192/68707)):

```
class PseudoDirEntry:
    def __init__(self, name, path, is_dir, stat):
        self.name = name
        self.path = path
        self._is_dir = is_dir
        self._stat = stat

    def is_dir(self):
        return self._is_dir

    def stat(self):
        return self._stat
```

Answer (score 5):

Even easier:

```
class PseudoDirEntry:
   def __init__(self, path):
      import os, os.path
      self.path = os.path.realpath(path)
      self.name = os.path.basename(self.path)
      self.is_dir = os.path.isdir(self.path)
      self.stat = lambda: os.stat(self.path)
```